# How can I modify parameters of a sinamics from a PLC

Tags: plc

I have just started to work with PLCs and I need to modify parameters of a sinamics from a PLC. I know that they may have different accesible levels and that they are modified by functions. So the question is:

Can I the parameters be directly modified?
 Or if it is not possible, how do I programm and include that functions?

Answer (score 0):

At least try to find some information.

http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/view/en/34677186/136000&cspltfrm=39&cssw=0&csbinh=8

Answer (score 0):

Sinamics drives parameters can be modified from the plc code using _writedriveparameter function. 
One thing to remember is: never use this function in two places at the same time. If you do it the function hangs and to restore the correct working it is necessary to reboot the cpu.
Also remember to check the function result to call the function in the correct way (result 7001,7002,7003 ecc). You have to check if the function is already working or not.